# Ejecutar test unitarios con Phpunit en lumen

Tags: php, laravel, php5, lumen, phpunit

Buenas tengo un proyecto de `lumen` con el archivo `phpunit` que viene por defecto que es tal como este

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
</php>
```

El fichero `.env` lo tengo de esta manera

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
```

Ahora voy a la consola y  ejecuto `phpunit` desde el directorio del proyecto y lo que recibo por pantalla es lo siguiente

```
PHPUnit 5.4.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

> Time: 37 ms, Memory: 8.00MB
>
> No tests executed!

Si miro la carpeta de tests veo los siguientes archivos

```
edu@pc1:/var/www/html/proyecto1/tests$ ls -alh
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x  2 edu edu 4,0K feb 28 13:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 edu edu 4,0K feb 28 13:23 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 edu edu  390 feb 16 16:53 ExampleTest.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 edu edu  279 feb 16 16:53 TestCase.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 edu edu  324 feb 28 13:35 UserTest.php
edu@pc1:/var/www/html/proyecto1/tests$
```

También he probado a ejecutar un `phpunit` de un solo archivo y recibo este **error:**

> edu@pc1:/var/www/html/proyecto1$ phpunit tests/TestCase.php 
>   Class 'tests/TestCase' could not be found in '/var/www/html/proyecto1/tests/TestCase.php'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te está reconociendo los tests porque los estás nombrando al revés.
Los nombres de las clases tienen que terminar en `Test` y los nombres de los métodos tienen que empezar con `test` o tener la anotación `@test`
Espero haberte sido de ayuda

renombrá `TestCase.php` por `CaseTest.php` y debería funcionar

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha solucionado el problema